# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.state.[prop].map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am new to React. I am building a component in Visual Studio 2017 where a user enters some text and, according to that, values are fetched from a database and shown in a `div`. Below is the class and interfaces I am using.

```
interface ISearchForm {
  suggestionList: ISuggestionList[];
  searchText: string;
}

interface ISuggestionList {
  queryDetails: IQueryDetails;
  data: IDataForUsers[];
}

interface IQueryDetails {
  search: string;
  returncount: number;
  skip: number;
  top: number;
}

interface IDataForUsers {
  users: IUsers[];
}

interface IUsers {
  profileId: string;
  firstName: string; 
  middleName: string;
  lastName: string;
}
```

The reason I have such a complex structure, is beacuse the API returns a complex JSON, like below:

```
"querydetails": {
  "search": "sample string 1",
  "returncount": 2,
  "skip": 3,
  "top": 4
},
"data": {
  "users": [{
    "profileId": "sample string 1",
    "firstName": "sample string 2", //I want to retrieve array of this key for every user
    "middleName": "sample string 3",
    "lastName": "sample string 4",
  }, {
    "profileId": "sample string 1",
    "firstName": "sample string 2",
    "middleName": "sample string 3",
    "lastName": "sample string 4",
  }]
}
```

Below is my class. Now this whole code is in typescript:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';
export class Search extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, 
ISearchForm> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { suggestionList: [], searchText: '' };
    this.handleSerachTextChange = this.handleSerachTextChange.bind(this);
  }//Some more code after this
}
```

On text change event, I make an API call and assign the response to `suggestionList[]`

```
handleSerachTextChange(e: any) {
    this.setState({ searchText: e.target.value });
    this.setState({ suggestionList: [] });
    if (e.target.value == '') {}
    else {
        var propsForAPI = { search: e.target.value, skip: 0, top: 10 };
        var jsonData = JSON.stringify(propsForAPI);

        fetch('apiURL', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: jsonData
        })
        .then(response => response.json() as Promise<ISuggestionList[]>)
        .then(data => {
             this.setState({ suggestionList: data });
        });
    }
}
```

This is what my render method looks like. It gives me an error on runtime, when I try to use `this.state.suggestionList.map()`.

The reason I created my inner `div` is because of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yh1DOKh4jas).

```
public render() {
    return <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.searchText} onChange={this.handleSerachTextChange} />
        <div>
            {
                this.state.suggestionList.map((dataArray) => {
                    <div>
                        {
                            dataArray.data.map((usersList) => {
                                <div>
                                    {
                                        usersList.users.map((userArray) => {
                                            <div>
                                                {
                                                    userArray.firstName
                                                }
                                            </div>
                                        })
                                    }
                                </div>
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                })
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Can somebody tell me why I am getting this error? Or how I can retrieve a list of `firstName`s for all of the users? I don't want to change the response that I am getting from my API call. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: consider making this a [runnable snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)  so others can go right into debugging your program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are expecting your JSON result to be of type `ISuggestionList[]`. But that does not match *at all*. You need to fix your types before attempting anything else.

- The JSON result is of type `ISuggestionList`, not an array of that type
- Similarly `data` inside `ISuggestionList` is also not an array but an object that has a `users` property. So it’s `IDataForUsers` (again no array).
- Since your JSON is only a single `ISuggestionList`, `ISearchForm` also shouldn’t have multiple `ISuggestionList` elements.

Once you have fixed that, you should get compiler errors that should guide you towards the right usage of your objects. Then you will also realize that you cannot use `map` on `state.suggestionList` because it’s not an array.

Also, you should really adjust the naming of your types. You should use singular names for things that represent a single thing, and not call something `List` when that isn’t an actual list of things.

Comment: Vote for not only answer but also instructive

Comment: @poke Your answer was so instructive that i got my output. I've been banging my head over this for two days. Really thanks man. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
.then(response => response.json() as Promise<ISuggestionList[]>)
.then(data => {
    this.setState({ suggestionList: data });
});
```

the `this.state.suggestionList` initially is an array, but that chunk of code set it as somewhat not an array.

Replace `this.setState({ suggestionList: data });` by `this.setState({ suggestionList: data.users });`

Comment: But when i console.log the suggestionList after this call, i can see all the data in it

Comment: console log your data type with `typeof data` to check if it is array or not.

Comment: I edit my answer, you can try it. the point is set `suggestionList` with `data.users`

Comment: okay i did console log for data as well as suggestionList. Both are of type object.

Comment: yup, at `constructor` your `suggestionList` is an array, then you set it with an object (because your `data` is an object) => so `suggestionList` became an object

Comment: @Khoa `typeof` is *not* a safe way to figure out what type something is.

Comment: @poke, agree but I just need to know it is array or not => so it's ok with `typeof`

Comment: @Khoa it gives me a compile time error if i do this.setState({ suggestionList: data.users }) saying Property 'users' does not exist on type ISuggestionList[]

Comment: @PrasaadPatil sorry, you are using typescript - a typesafe language. Now, you know the issue that you need to set your `suggestionList` with an array, not an object => do whatever need to get you a right one.

Comment: @Khoa No, it’s not. `typeof []` gives you `"object"`. The only safe way to check whether something is an array is using [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Comment: @poke nice => sorry my bad

Comment: @Khoa Okay. i need to specify that i am using typescript in my question :P. sorry

Answer (score 0):

If your `suggestionList` equals the data you receive, `data` is not an array but an object, you can't iterate on it. So, in my opinion you can just iterate on your users list like this:

Try updating your initial state with

```
this.state = { suggestionList: { data: null }, searchText: '' };
```

then update your render like

```
<div>
  {
     this.state.suggestionList.data ?
       this.state.suggestionList.data.users.map(user => <div>{user.firstName}</div>) : 
       null
  }
</div>
```

Comment: its gives me a compile time error. Property 'users' does not exist on type 'ISuggestionList[]'

Comment: I get it, set your state like `this.setState({ suggestionList: data.data });` or update the map with `this.state.suggestionList.data.users.map`.

Comment: still gives me the same compile time error :(. it is not allowing to put me data after suggestionList

Comment: Because your initial state does not contains this properties. Ok, I will edit my code.

Comment: i am getting an error on data. it is not allowing me to put .data after suggestion list

Comment: Back to the old one. It could be useful to print your data to see exactly what it looks like before updating the state. Try with `users` directly like my edit.

Comment: Nope. Still gives me compile time error. If i print data i get the json i have mentioned above. data:{users: Array(10)} is what i see in my console

Comment: Basically it gives me a compile time error every time i try to use data or users properties :( i am using the above code as it is in visual studio

Comment: With the proper initial state setting data to `null` and the ternary condition you should not have any errors. We miss something.

Comment: if i change the initial state to what you said it gives me compile time error => { suggestionList: { data: null }, searchText: '' } is not assignable to type 'Readonly<ISearchForm>'

Comment: This is because `interface ISearchForm {
  suggestionList: ISuggestionList[];
  searchText: string;
}
`. In your interface, suggestionList is still an Array. But in fact, it is an object.

Comment: Yo.. i removed the [] from the interface so that it can be an object. Now { suggestionList: { data: null }, searchText: '' }; is working fine but now it gives me same compile time error on this.state

Comment: Yeah.. After the changes suggested by @poke it was actually your last edit that solved the problem.. So thanks a lot for your time man

Comment: Glad to help :) Happy coding !